# List all pages in a Jekyll site by date last updated

Tags: date, jekyll

I'm using the [last_modified_at](https://github.com/gjtorikian/jekyll-last-modified-at) plugin to display the most recent version of each page of my Jekyll site on each page and it works like a charm.

**Question: How do I list all of the pages on the site, most recently updated to oldest?**

I can create a list of all pages for the entire site with:

```
{% for page in site.pages %}
{{ page.title}} | {{ page.last_modified_at | date: '%s' }}
{% endfor %}
```

It shows the title and then the UTC time that the page was last updated.

The goal is to order this list by the `last_modified_at` date.

How do I build this correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sort` filter :

```
{% assign sorted = site.pages | sort: 'last_modified_at' %}
```

Comment: I tried that, but I get a strange result and the dates are not in order.

Comment: Any repository url ?